# jQuery: How to create a Plugin that can be enabled and disabled?

Tags: jquery, html, button, plugins, onclick

Suppose I have this:

**1) Start Button.**

**2) Stop Button.**

**3) removePluginBtn**

**4) 2 Divs.**

I come up with a basic `jQuery` plugin like:

```
;(function(myPlugIn){

      myPlugIn.fn.styleTheDivAndAnimate = function (){

    $(this).css({background:"red",border:"10px solid black", padding:"30px"}).animate({marginLeft:"200px"},5000)

    }
    })(jQuery);



 $(function(){

        $('#startBtn').on('click',function(){

            $('#myDiv').styleTheDivAndAnimate()
        })

    })
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main" style="float:left;">

   <div id="myDiv" style="background:green; border:5px solid blue; padding:10px;">

   </div>

</div>

<button id="startBtn">Start</button>
<button id="stopBtn">Stop</button>
<button id="removePluginBtn">Unbind Plugin</button>
```

Now, when I click the `startBtn`, the `myDiv` gets bound the `styleTheDivAndAnimate` plugin.

However, what i want is when I click the `stopBtn`, `myDiv` should Simply *Go back* to the original status and when the `startBtn` is clicked again, it will be bound back to the `styleTheDivAndAnimate` as expected...

BUT...When I click the `removePluginBtn`... `myDiv` should no longer be bound to the `styleTheDivAndAnimate` plugin. even when I click the `startBtn` again, NO THING SHOULD HAPPEN because the plugin has  been removed from it...(something like that).

How can that be possibly achieved?

Thanx in advance!

***PLAESE SEE THE FIDDLE TO START WITH:*** http://jsfiddle.net/97AWD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the plugin, you can do:

```
jQuery.fn.styleTheDivAndAnimate = function() {};
```

This simply redefines the plugin to a function that does nothing.

If you want to disable on specific elements, use `.data()`:

```
$(this).data('styleTheDivAndAnimate-disabled', 'true');
```

Then in your main plugin code, wrap it with:

```
if (!$(this).data('styleTheDivAndAnimate-disabled')) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

FULL CODE: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/97AWD/4/)

```
;
(function (myPlugIn) {

    myPlugIn.fn.styleTheDivAndAnimate = function (action) {
        switch (action) {
            case 'disable':
                $(this).data('styleTheDivAndAnimate-disabled', 'true');
                break;
            case 'remove':
                $(this).css({
                    background: 'green',
                    border: '5px solid blue',
                    padding: '10px',
                    marginLeft: 0
                });
                break;
            default:
                if (!$(this).data('styleTheDivAndAnimate-disabled')) {
                    $(this).css({
                        background: "red",
                        border: "10px solid black",
                        padding: "30px"
                    }).animate({
                        marginLeft: "200px"
                    }, 5000);
                }
                break;
        }

    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: what if i still wanted the behavior on some other elements...EXCEPT this specific one?... i guess this way might disable the plugin universally... which may terror.

Comment: Sure looks great but pardon my LayManess cz I cant seem to get how to apply that... Could you please show it practically in a fiddle??... i'D 100% APPRECIATE.. thx already!

Comment: Pretty Cool... With your Idea, atleast I have come up with something close to what I really Wanted... I got no other option than to accept your answer. Thanx a million for the help. Just incase you think of other possibilities, please just add them here... I'd deeply appreciate again.